# Multiple TXT DNS records for domain

Tags: domains, dns

Am I allowed to add multiple TXT records for a single domain?

I've been asked to add a load of MS= records to domains, but some of the domains already have a TXT record.

Can I just add a new TXT record with the value or should I append it to the existing data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Multiple TXT DNS records are perfectly acceptable. In fact, I think one of my domains has about 6 of them. If you append it to the end of another TXT record, it is likely to stop that one performing it's correct function.

Answer (score 6):

In Amazon's DNS tool, Route53, if you're trying to create multiple TXT values that share the same `name`, you should surround each value in quotes and separate by a carriage return.

From the Route53 docs:

> ```
> A text record. Enter multiple values 
>     on separate lines. Enclose text in 
>     quotation marks.
> Example:
>     "Sample Text Entries" 
>     "Enclose entries in quotation marks"
> ```